# Настройка шага сетки

Tags: python, matplotlib

Нужно настроить в этом коде шаг сетки 1 по вертикали и по горизонтали.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as ax
import pylab
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.lines as lines
import matplotlib.ticker as xaxis

pylab.xlim (0, 30)
pylab.ylim (-45, 40)

c=1.006
def d_for_id (J,t):
    D=(J-1.006*t)*1000/(2501+1.805*t)
    return D
def t_for_id1 (J,d):
    t_for_id=(J-2501*(d/1000))/(c+1.805*(d/1000))
    return t_for_id
def D (P,T,F):
    Ph=10**((156+(8.12*T))/(236+T))*133.22
    vlaga=622*(F/100*Ph)/(P-F/100*Ph)
    return vlaga 
P=99000
F=10
T=np.arange (-45,50,1)
while F <110:
    x=D (P,T,F)
    y=T
    print (D (P,T,F))
    plt.plot(x,y,'-',color='black', lw='1.5')
    F=F+10
c=1.006
def d_for_id (J,t):
    D=(J-1.006*t)*1000/(2501+1.805*t)
    return D
def t_for_id1 (J,d):
    t_for_id=(J-2501*(d/1000))/(c+1.805*(d/1000))
    return t_for_id
n=-1
J=-20
t=-20
while n<6:
    d=0 
    n=n+1
    J=J+2
    if n==5:
        n=0
        t=t+5
    if t>20:
        t=20
    if J==126:
        break
    d1=d_for_id (J,t)
    t1=t_for_id1 (J,d)
    print (d1,t1)
    lines = plt.plot((0,d1),(t1,t), '-',color='black')
pylab.grid()
figure = plt.gcf() # get current figure
figure.set_size_inches(20, 28)  
plt.show()
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Почему вы не можете сделать это сами?

Comment: Переформатируйте код. Очень сложно читать. Советую прочитать: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете сделать метки вручную, методом `pylab.xticks(range(30))` и `pylab.yticks(range(-45, 40))`.